# Is it possible to pass a single variable containing many parameters to an Insert query ln TableAdapter?

Tags: vb.net, tableadapter

I'm working with TableAdapter on VS, and have something like this:

```
TableAdapter.Insert(parameter1,parameter2,parameter3,...,parameterN)
```

And would like to know if is it possible to pass a single variable containing those parameters instead, and get something like this:

```
TableAdapter.Insert(all_parameters)
```

NOTE: I would like to know because I have sometimes a lot of parameters to pass and the line code becomes very large

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word; no. The TableAdapter `Insert` method is generated in response to the GenerateDBDirect checkbox being ticked during the tableadapter wizard setup, and the direct methods for Insert/Update/Delete only exist in the format that you see

That being said, you can pass a strongly typed DataRow to the Update method, as it has overloads that are intended for persisting changes in a dataset/datatable/collection of datarow/single datarow, to a database

This means you could, instead of doing the following to insert a row:

```
personTA.Insert("John", "Smith", 30, "1 The Road");
```

Build a datarow that is state Added, and Update it, which will cause the SQL INSERT to be run:

```
var ro = personDataTable.NewPersonRow();
ro.FirstName = "John";
ro.LastName = "Smith";
ro.Age = 30;
ro.Address = "1, The Road";
personDataTable.AddPersonRow(ro);

//even though it's called Update, this will insert the record to the table, because it's RowState is Added
personTA.Update(ro);
```

This is more the way TableAdapters were intended to be used: you'd bind the datarow to text boxes, the user would type in them, and then you'd use Update() to save the changes to the database. You haven't really had to do any work in doing so, and it's hence less laborious to code, than doing something like:

```
personTA.Insert(_firstNameTextBox.Text, _lastNameTextBox.Text, …)
```

When you work with strongly typed datasets, databound textboxes etc can be created with a simple drag operation, by pulling a relevant node out of the DataSOurces window and dropping it onto the form. If you aren't using this / don't have a UI / aren't databinding then consider that there are some other ways you can make your life easier.. If your data is already in an array, then you could just set the ItemArray of the row:

```
var ro = personDataTable.NewPersonRow();
ro.ItemArray = array_with_person_data;
personDataTable.AddPersonRow(ro);
personTA.Update(ro);
```

Apologies that this is C# syntax; I've just seen that you've tagged VB. There are, however, no significant differences in the two syntaxes for this particular aspect of coding - I think mentally removing the semicolons and changing `var` to `Dim` would be all that's required to turn this particular C# into VB

Edit:

Don't forget that you're typically allowed to add your own code to anything that Microsoft provide for you in a designer. If you double click a tableadapter in the design surface you'll be taken to an empty partial class where you can add another/your own overload of `Insert`, perhaps one that takes an array and then simply calls the generated Insert, using all the parameters in order:

```
Namespace YourProgram.YourDataSetTableAdapters{

    Partial Class YourTableAdapter

        //ADD YOUR OWN INSERT METHOD HERE
        Public Function Insert(things as Object()){
            Return this.Insert( _
              DirectCast(things[0] as String), _
              DirectCast(things[1] as String), _
              DirectCast(things[2] as Int32), _
              DirectCast(things[0] as String) _
            )
        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

I've guessed at this VB; it might have syntax errors, hopefully you get the idea